# How to get a name of last migration programmatically?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I want to get the name of the last applied migration in Django. I know that Django migrations are stored in `django_migrations` table, however `django.db.migrations.migration.Migration` is not a `models.Model` backed by that table. This means you cannot do:

```
migration_info = Migration.objects.all()
```

Is there any built-in way of retrieveing the data from `django_migrations`, or should i just create my own read-only Model:

```
class MigrationInfo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = "django_migrations"
```

Comment: Would it be an option to just read the contents of the migrations folder and get the last-added file? This would use the Python 'os' package.

Comment: maybe this would help https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.2/django/core/management/commands/showmigrations.py#L38-L77

Comment: @RobinPapa not all migrations in the folder can be applied

Comment: @MariuszJamro Please consider adding more detail or accepting an answer as this question is quite old still active.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This works on Django 1.11/1.8/2.1 & 3.0.4:

```
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder

last_migration = MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.latest('id')
print(last_migration.app)     # The app where the migration belongs
print(last_migration.name)    # The name of the migration
```

There doesn't seem to be documentation for this command, but [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/recorder.py) you may find the source code which is documented properly.

Comment: Works on Django 1.8

Comment: Works up to Django 2.1 as well.

Comment: Works for me in 3.0.4!

Comment: Works on Django 4.0

Answer (score 6):

To store information about applied migrations Django uses plain table and it is accessible as [@classproperty](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/decorators.py#L167) through the `MigrationRecorder` class:

```
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder

lm = MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.filter(app='core').last()
```

---

It is also easy to retrieve this information from the command line:

#### Get the last applied migration for the particular app

```
python manage.py showmigrations --list <app_name> | grep "\[X\]" | tail -1
```

#### Get the ordered list of unapplied migrations

```
python manage.py showmigrations --plan | grep "\[ \]"
```

Comment: Can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639768/unable-to-migrate-using-modelstate-and-projectstate-using-of-migrations-api-in-d unable to use model_create as well as projectstate and modelstate as well to apply migrations. The fields have been specified right and have tried even the testcase way of creating models. Do I have to call addfield removefield specifically in migrations?

Answer (score -3):

A lot easier, you could also parse out the last line of:

`./manage.py showmigrations <app_name>`

Comment: This won't work as the output of showmigrations is ordered by app name, and the last line could be a migration that hasn't run yet. @Dariem Pérez Herrera's solution is the correct way imo