# Django migrate rollback multiple migrations on failure

Tags: django, django-migrations

Django migrations has excellent behavior in terms of single migrations, where, assuming you leave `atomic=True`, a migration will be all-or-nothing: it will either run to completion or undo everything.

Is there a way to get this all-or-nothing behavior for multiple migrations?  That is to say, is there a way to either run multiple migrations inside an enclosing transaction (which admittedly could cause [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12838111/2800876)) or to rollback all succeeded migrations on failure?

For context, I'm looking for a single command or setting to do this so that I can include it in a deploy script.  Currently, the only part of my deploy that isn't rolled back in the event of a failure are database changes.  I know that this can be manually done by running `python manage.py migrate APP_NAME MIGRATION_NUMBER` in the event of a failure, but this requires knowledge of the last run migration on each app.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, there was some [discussion](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24535) back in 2015 about supporting this, along with some reasoning about why it wasn't included as a feature. I think it's a good question though, and something that should be reconsidered for certain databases that support transactional DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a feature in Django (at least as of 4.1).  To do this yourself, your code needs to do the following:

1. Get a list of current apps that have migrations.  This can be done by getting the intersection of apps from settings.INSTALLED_APPS and the apps in the MigrationRecorder.
2. [Get the latest migration for each app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59261486/2800876).
3. [Run migrations.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907743/2800876)
4. If migrations fail, run the rollback command for the latest migration for each app.

Here's an implementation of this as a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/): https://github.com/zagaran/django-migrate-or-rollback.  This is done as a child-class of the migrate management command so that it exposes all of the command line options of migrate.  To use this library, `pip install django-migrate-or-rollback` and add `"django_migrate_or_rollback"` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py.  Then you can use `python manage.py migrate_or_rollback` in place of the traditional `migrate` command.

Disclosure: I am the author of the library referenced (though I made the library based on this StackOverflow answer).